# linq query to get dependent data in one connection using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following SQL Statements:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, @UserID = UserID 
FROM Users 
WHERE UserName = <username> AND Password = <password>

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM ClientUser 
WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

There are two select statements in the above queries, one to get the `UserID`,other column information from `Users` table and second one to get information from another table based on `@UserID` value. How to write a `linq` query on `entity framework` context to do this selection without connecting to database multiple times?

Comment: You can use linq join to join both tables based on userid and then fetch . This way it will use only one db hit

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have two classes, User and ClientUser that are part of your entity framework model.  They might look something like this.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    //More to be here

    public virtual ICollection<ClientUser> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class ClientUser
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

The default situation would have you working with lazy loaded since I have these defined as Virtuals.  If you know you need more, just do something like this

```
var query = YourContext.Users.Get().Include(x => x.Clients);
```

Then add what you need to the query.  By using "include" it ensures that EF pulls the data eagerly rather than lazily.